# How to use jq to count all instances of a field that is nested numerically in an array?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json structure that looks like:

```
{  
   "main":[  
      {  
            "0":[ {"0":"..."},{"1":"..."},{"2":"..."},{"3":"..."} ]
      },
      {  
            "1":[ {"0":"..."},{"1":"..."},{"2":"..."} ]
      },
      {  
            "2":[ {"0":"..."},{"1":"..."},{"2":"..."},{"3":"..."},{"4":"..."} ]
      }
    ]
}
```

What I would like is to be able to count the total number of elements within each direct child of `"main"`. For example, in the above, `"main"` has an array containing 3 direct childs, `"0", "1", "2"`. For `"0"`, we have 4 such elements, `"1"` we have 3 such elements, and `"2"` we have 5 such elements.

Is there a way to use `jq` to return `12` as the final answer for the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count all scalars in the document:

```
jq '[..|scalars] | length'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3BPM3wgqZ8o)

If you just want to consider the tree under `.main`, prepend it:

```
jq '.main | [..|scalars] | length'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DOjteav9sgC)

If there's many elements and you don't want to buid up an intermediate array, only needed to take its length from, count on the fly using `reduce`:

```
jq 'reduce (..|scalars) as $_ (0; .+1)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nkOYJEDwy5x)

Answer (score 1):

This produces 12 for your sample input:

```
[.main[][] | length] | add
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7cSBsnzj34Y)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Double map + length + add:

```
.main|map(map(length)|add)|add
```

Or

```
.main|map(map(length))|add|add
```

Or stream all values first, wrap in array and get array length (this is probably the <s>sexiest</s> shortest, but not very memory-efficient):

```
[.main[][][]]|length
```

If memory is an issue or you have a huge number of elements, use `reduce` as suggested by @peak in another answer

Answer (score 1):

It might not matter in many cases, but constructing arrays just for the sake of counting is inefficient. In any case, it’s nice to have the following stream-oriented def in your quiver:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $_ (0; .+1);
```

With that, you can e.g. write:

```
count(.main[][][])
```